# Does a DLQ on a Lambda invoked by an S3 event notification handle invocation errors and runtime errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

**Background**:

On object creation in an S3 bucket, an event notification is sent to asynchronously invoke a Lambda function.

A DLQ has been added to the Lambda function to explore error-handling and retry mechanisms for errors **during** the Lambda execution.

Breaking this down in simpler terms (abstracting away the complexity):

- Creation: S3 object created
- Notification: S3 event notification sent to Lambda
- Invocation: Lambda is attempted to be asynchronously invoked
- Execution: Lambda is invoked successfully and is currently being executed

**Question**:

Does the DLQ added to the Lambda account for errors occurring **during** the **invocation** i.e. pre-execution of the Lambda? I know the DLQ accounts for errors occurring during the **execution** of the Lambda

Comment: What are examples of errors that occur at "pre-execution of the Lambda"?

Comment: Hi @Marcin 

Examples of Lambda invocation errors include errors caused by issues with request parameters, event structure, function settings, user permissions, resource permissions, or limits.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-invocation.html

Comment: In that case, please try what happens with such errors and let us know what you have discovered.